# Android Studio Rendering problems Classes coudnt be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

> - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I get this error each time i try to switch from AppTheme to holo light/dark, material light/dark

Yes I have AS v 1.4, tested with nexus 4 and 5, and with Api 23 till 19.
I also tried turning it on and off again :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and worked.

1. Clean project
2. Rebuild project
3. Sync Gradle
4. Regresh the layout preview

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with changing **Preview Android Version** with check outing `Automatically Pick Best` and check API i used in application.

[image]